# VertexArray glVertexAttribPointer GL_INVALID_VALUE 0x0501

Tags: c++, opengl, vertex-buffer

Writing an OpenGL program to draw a square on screen, but running into an invalid value error. The error occurs on the call `MyGLCall(glVertexAttribPointer(i,`. `MyGLCall` is an abstraction of `GLCALL` to I can have the error code printed to the console as below.

Not sure value is invalid here. I believe all the data types are correct for [glVertexAttribPointer](http://docs.gl/gl4/glVertexAttribPointer), bu missing something here.

**Console output**

```
Rendering...
OpenGL version 3.3.0 NVIDIA 388.13
GL Extension Wrangler version 2.1.0
[!!! OpenGL ERROR!!!] (0x0501)
glVertexAttribPointer(i, element.elements_per_vertex, element.type, element.normalized, layout.get_stride(), (const void*) offset)
```

**Layout and Element Data Types**

[image]

**Source code**

```
// bind vertex buffer and set memory layout
void VertexArray::add_buffer(const VertexBuffer& vb, const VertexBufferLayout& layout) 
{
    VertexArray::bind();
    vb.bind();
    // auto is std::vector<VertexBufferLayoutElement>
    const auto& elements = layout.get_elements();
    unsigned int offset = 0;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < elements.size(); i++) 
    {       
        const auto& element = elements[i];      
        // GL_INVALID_VALUE 0x0501
        MyGLCall(glEnableVertexAttribArray(i));
        MyGLCall(glVertexAttribPointer(i,
            element.elements_per_vertex,
            element.type,
            element.normalized,
            layout.get_stride(),
            (const void*) offset)); // heckin, what is this (const void*)???
        offset += element.elements_per_vertex * VertexBufferLayoutElement::get_size_of_type(element.type);
    }   
}
```

**struct for VertexBufferLayoutElement in my VertextBufferLayout Header file**

```
struct VertexBufferLayoutElement
{
    // nice mem alignment bro, mem size on most machines is
    unsigned int elements_per_vertex;   // 4 bytes
    unsigned int type;                  // 4 bytes
    unsigned char normalized;           // 1 byte
    static unsigned int get_size_of_type(unsigned int type)
    {
        switch (type)
        {
            case GL_FLOAT:          return 4;
            case GL_UNSIGNED_INT:   return 4;
            case GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE:  return 1;
        }
        ASSERT(false);
        return 0;
    }
};
```

**Error was in this header file above**

Did not follow the correct parameter order of the the [first c spec parameter list for the arrtrib pointer function](http://docs.gl/gl4/glVertexAttribPointer). `GL_FLOAT` and `elements_per_vertex` were swapped causing the error, the screenshot below is the correct order.

[image]

Comment: What are the values of `layout.get_stride()` and `element.elements_per_vertex`?

Comment: @Rabbid76 added a screenshot with types

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 2nd parameter of [`glVertexAttribPointer`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glVertexAttribPointer.xhtml) is the tuple size and has to be 1, 2, 3, 4 or `GL_BGRA`. The 3rd parameter is the type (e.g. `GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE`, `GL_FLOAT`).

You pass `element.elements_per_vertex` to the 2nd and `element.type` to the 3rd parameter which seems to be correct. But the values of the parameters are swapped:

> ```non
> elements_per_vertex : 5126
> type                : 3
> ```

Note, 5126 is 0x1406 and this is the value of the enumerator constant `GL_FLOAT`.

Set

```
elements_per_vertex = 3
type = GL_FLOAT
```

to solve the issue.

Comment: Funky: "When *size* is `BGRA`, it indicates four values. The values within each array element are stored sequentially in memory. However, **if *size* is `BGRA`, the first, second, third, and fourth values of each array element are taken from the third, second, first, and fourth values in memory respectively.**"

Comment: That fixed it! Thanks so much, when I construct a new VertexBufferLayoutElement and `push_back` on my collection of all of these elements I swapped `type` and `elements_per_vertex` (which the docs call size). I think I'll call `elements_per_vertex` something like vertex components in the future since it's always RGBA sounds like.